# Django shell does not let me query models

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query my customized user model "RmkUser" through the django shell, but it keeps raising an error when I try to command "from models import RmkUser":

**RuntimeError: Model class models.RmkUser doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.**

I am not sure why it does this, nor was I able to find out through other posts. I saw that there are a lot of posts which show problems with this error, too, but I can't find a solution for my specific case.

I don't understand why django asks me to declare my customized user model "RmkUser" under INSTALLED_APPS. After all, its a model, not an app. My app (as opposed to the "RmkUser" model), however, is entered under INSTALLED_APPS and it also has an app_label. Also, I did set AUTH_USER_MODEL to my customized user model. Not only that, but my site is actually running completely fine when I "python manage.py runserver". I can create new users, log in, etc, no problem.

Does anybody know how I can get the shell to let me query the "RmkUser" model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Models have to be in an app. You can’t have a model that’s not in an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import a custom model, you need to specify which app it will come, try:

```
from yourapp.models import RmkUser
```

Comment: @Raku, yes you have to command it and import it before you can use the custom user model, even if you use the default user model. You still have to import the `User` model

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `shell_plus` from `django_extension`. It will load your models at the first time running. Simple to use, just run the below command

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

Or you can see the detail [here](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html)